# How to get file in directory device in android?

Tags: android, directory, device, subdirectory

i create simple application mediaplayer,and i want to get all file .mp3 in device android. below my code :

```
File home = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
if (home.listFiles().length > 0) {
    for (File file : home.listFiles()) {
        Log.e("test", file.getPath());
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            Log.e("tesnyae", file.getPath());
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
} else {}
```

but when i using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` cannot get all .mp3 in device , still available subfolder, if i using specific folder can't get all file,
are there solution to auto get all file .mp3 in android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recursively loop all the directories to find all the .mp3 files.

You can create a function like this:

```
    public void findAudioInFolder(File folder) {
        if (folder.listFiles().length > 0) {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                Log.e("test", file.getPath());
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    Log.e("tesnyae", file.getPath());
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0,(file.getName().length() - 4)));
                    song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                    songsList.add(song);
                } 
                else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    findAudioInFolder(file);
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
```

And you call it as:

```
File home = new   File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
findAudioInFolder(home);
```

---

**updated:** I realized that there maybe a case that you have a **folder** named xxx.mp3. So you need to check if the file is a directory first.  Modify the code as following:

```
    public void findAudioInFolder(File folder) {
        if (folder.listFiles().length > 0) {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                Log.e("test", file.getPath());

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    findAudioInFolder(file);
                }
                else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    Log.e("tesnyae", file.getPath());
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0,(file.getName().length() - 4)));
                    song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                    songsList.add(song);
                } 

            }
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: loop all diretories ?
how to create it ? sorry i'm new android

Answer (score 2):

As Vigor mentioned, you'll need to recursively loop through the subdirectories of external storage. Right now you're just checking files/directories in external storage root. Something like this should work:

```
File home = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
checkForMp3Recursive(home);
```

Then:

```
private void checkForMp3Recursive(File file) {
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
    if (file.listFiles().length > 0) {
      for (File innerFile : file.listFiles()) {
        checkForMp3Recursive(innerFile);
      }
    }
  } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
    Log.e("tesnyae", file.getPath());
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4));
    song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

    songList.add(song);
  }
}
```